# View is getting shifted every time I re-tap textfield

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

so I have a small app where I choose an image, get it into an image view
and I have 2 textfield to insert a funny phrase

(Meme editor app)
my problem is since the bottom textfield is covered when the keyboard is shown I had to shift the view upwards every time the keyboard is shown for the bottom texfield and I succeed in doing that, what goes wrong is that every time I re-tap the beginning or the end of an existing text in the text filed the view shifts up again in undesirable behavior

[here is a small GIF that shows what happens exactly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DomSP.gif)

here is my code so far:

Function to get Kyboard height:

```
func getKeyboardHeight(_ notification:Notification) -> CGFloat {
        let userInfo = notification.userInfo
        let keyboardSize = userInfo![UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue // of CGRect
        return keyboardSize.cgRectValue.height
    }
```

Function to shift the view up in the condition that bottom textfield is what the user taps

```
@objc func keyboardWillShow(_ notification:Notification) {
        if bottomTextField.isFirstResponder{
            view.frame.origin.y -= getKeyboardHeight(notification)
        }
    }
```

Function to return the view to its normal position when the user finishes editing the bottom text field

```
@objc func keyboardWillHide(_ notification:Notification) {
    view.frame.origin.y = 0
}
```

Functions to add and remove observers of keyboard notifications

```
func subscribeToKeyboardNotifications() {
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow(_:)), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
    }

func subscribekeyboardWillHide() {
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide(_:)), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
    }

func unsubscribeFromKeyboardNotifications() {
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
    }

func unsubscribekeyboardWillHide() {
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
    }
```

and where I call them

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    
    super .viewWillAppear(true)
    cameraButton.isEnabled = UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.camera)
    subscribeToKeyboardNotifications()
    subscribekeyboardWillHide()
    
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    unsubscribeFromKeyboardNotifications()
    unsubscribekeyboardWillHide()
    
}
```

if you could be kind to provide a simple explanation for your solution I would appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

Every time you change the cursor location, `UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification` notification triggered, thats why every time you tap the textfield it moves up one keyboard height more.

You can use `UIResponder.keyboardDidShowNotification` notification instead of `UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification`. This one is not triggered when cursor location changes.

Comment: while I've tried using keyboardDidShowNotification i still got the same problem but also I need the text field to transition with the keyboard appearance, not after the keyboard it transition is over

Answer (score 0):

This is what I do while managing keyboard. It causes no problems.

Declare in your UIViewController class

```
private let notificationCenter = NotificationCenter.default
```

then in

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(adjustForKeyboard), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
        notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(adjustForKeyboard), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillChangeFrameNotification, object: nil)
    }
```

This is the adjust for keyboard function

```
@objc private func adjustForKeyboard(notification: Notification) {
        guard let userInfo = notification.userInfo else { return }
        guard let keyboardScreenEndFrame = (userInfo[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue else { return }
        let keyboardViewEndFrame = view.convert(keyboardScreenEndFrame, from: view.window)
        if notification.name == UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification {
            scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets.zero
        } else {
            scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: keyboardViewEndFrame.height, right: 0)
        }
        scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = scrollView.contentInset
    }
```

Deinit here -

```
 override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidDisappear(true)

        notificationCenter.removeObserver(self, name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
        notificationCenter.removeObserver(self, name: UIResponder.keyboardWillChangeFrameNotification, object: nil)
    }
```

Comment: couldn't adjust it to use it with text field, I am new to ios and I don't know if I am missing anything

Comment: @Parzivle Don't forget to add textField.delegate = self in viewDidLoad()
This works best when you embed your view in a scroll view.
For example, create a scroll view and add a subview named contentView and inside this contentView add all of your views which you have added in your code currently.

It should work fine then